# Fluid css grid framework for Mobile site only

Tags: html, css, mobile, fluid-layout

I am looking to start a mobile website only. Not responsive. I am going to be using HTML5 boilerplate for mobile.

I know there are lots of css fluid frameworks out there, but just wanted to know what you guys think is best and if there is on specifically that works best with HTML5 boilerplate? Mainly work best for mobile.

I am not using jQuery Mobile. It will just be HTML, CSS and standard jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: The new (v. 4.0) [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) is mobile-first kind of framework.

Comment: are there any good examples out there to see the grid in all its glory for the mobile framework?

Comment: Sure ... http://foundation.zurb.com/case-jacquelinewest.php

Answer (score 0):

I generally use [320 and up](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup) from Andy Clarke. This one is a full framework, so it might be more than you need.

The other option is grabbing just the responsive grid from [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and plugging it into your framework. Bootstrap can also be used as a stand-alone solution as well.

Comment: Would the 960gs fluid grid system do the job for mobile? Basically any fluid grid system should work on mobile?

Comment: Last I checked, the 960gs was not fluid.  The reason I suggested Bootstrap is that they have a percentage-based fluid grid system that is quite easy to use. Here is the link to their demo page, you can resize your browser window to see it working: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem